# whats wrong with this Arithmetic operation?

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

When i write for example:

```
double d = (4/3)*6;
```

Why does it sees 4/3 as 1(int?) not 1.333 and the result is 6 not 8?

Thanks.

Comment: use the d after you numbers to indicate that they are double es. (4d/3d)

Answer (score 2):

`4/3` is equal to `1`, since it's dividing two integers using integer division. `4.0/3` will give you the result you expect, since it will use floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the value in integer arethmetic and asigning the result to a double value, however the result is still a whole number. You can force floating point arithmetic, by making the first operand a double (or if they are input variables multiply with 1.0):

```
double d = (4.0/3)*6;
```

If the values are inputs:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 3;
int c = 6;
```

You can force the conversion by multiplying with 1.0:

```
double d = (a*1.0/b)*c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because every number without a specification is handelt as an integer.

If you use `1.0` it will be a double.

For the other formates you could use `1f` for float, `1l` for long or an other way to represent a double would be `1d`.